# Symfony FOSUserBundle - cant login by email

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony 2.8 and FOSUserBundle and I can't login by email to my application.

My `security.yml` contains the

```
providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
```

but even that I'm getting an `Invalid credentials` error :/ Profiler for the `POST /login_check` is saying that Doctrine generate query just for the username:

```
SELECT t0.username AS username_1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical_2, t0.email AS email_3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical_4, t0.enabled AS enabled_5, t0.salt AS salt_6, t0.password AS password_7, t0.last_login AS last_login_8, t0.locked AS locked_9, t0.expired AS expired_10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at_11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_13, t0.roles AS roles_14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired_15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at_16, t0.id AS id_17 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the ever popular clearing of the cache?  Though I suspect you may be running in development mode.

Comment: Is there any further details in the logs file?

Comment: Clearing the cache didnt helped :/

Comment: The log is just warning about deprecated functions - nothing special related to above problem.
Why the hell the doctrine is building the query with `WHERE t0.username_canonical` :/